# MySQL update table1 by table1 + table2 then set table2 to 0

Tags: mysql

I have tables `resources`, `building`. My query should explain what I'm trying to do:

```
update building b, resources r
        set
            r.wood = r.wood + b.storage,
            b.storage = 0
        where
            b.castle_id = r.castle_id and
            b.name = 'wood_farm'
```

I've tried other ways like using join or swap `building` and `resources` but nothing works. I tried something like `r.wood = r.wood + (select sum(storage) etc)` but that doesn't work for some reason. Besides I wouldn't be able to compare aliases (at least for what I tried).

What doesn't work? There are 2 buildings named `wood_farm`. They are linked to resources via `castle_id`. Lets say 2 buildings have `storage = 5`. This query will make resources equal 5 instead of what I want which is 10 (5 storage + 5 storage). Now both wood_farm buildings storage will equal 0.

I can understand why this doesn't work, but I can't find a solution.

```
building  | id, castle_id, name, storage, etc, speed, etc, deleted, etc
resources | id, castle_id, wood, stone, etc, etc, deleted, etc
castle    | id, other stuff, etc
```

MySQL version

```
innodb_version 5.6.34
protocol_version 10
version 5.6.34-log
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os Linux
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data set and table definitions ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I don't want to sound dumb but I hope my edit is what you are asking for. I'm not an sql person.

Comment: Its better if you also provide the sample data for your tables a good idea to provide your schema and data details using http://sqlfiddle.com/ and add the link in your post

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Well I made this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76fa7/5 which isn't exactly every column, since I don't think that's needed especially since I just started this game, but the default values, how it's organized, etc are the exact same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this (adding another subselect who makes the SUM of storage):

```
    UPDATE building b, resources r
          , (SELECT CASTLE_ID, NAME, SUM(STORAGE) AS STORAGE FROM building GROUP BY CASTLE_ID, NAME) b2
          SET r.wood = r.wood+b2.storage, b.storage=0
    WHERE b.castle_id = r.castle_id AND b.name = 'wood_farm'
           AND b2.castle_id=r.castle_id AND b2.name=b.name
     ;
```

and he did the update as requested.  But I think you should do some checks to be sure it always do it.

Output:

```
ID  CASTLE_ID   NAME    STORAGE
1   2   wood_farm   0
1   3   iron_farm   10

ID  CASTLE_ID   WOOD
1   2   19
1   3   6
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING (ID INT, CASTLE_ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), STORAGE INT);
CREATE TABLE RESOURCES (ID INT, CASTLE_ID INT,  WOOD INT);
INSERT INTO BUILDING VALUES (1, 2, 'wood_farm', 10);
INSERT INTO BUILDING VALUES (1, 3, 'iron_farm', 10);
INSERT INTO BUILDING VALUES (1, 2, 'wood_farm', 4);
INSERT INTO RESOURCES VALUES (1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO RESOURCES VALUES (1, 3, 6);
```

Comment: @Hybrilynx  I added another updated version, with sum and group by (after you posted your sample data in sqlfiddle)

Comment: I made an edit with mysql versions. Because (select sum(storage) etc) doesn't work. Your first answer seems like it has a syntax error in my phpmyadmin. Though I've been trying with selected the 2nd build b2 but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: Maybe for your answer they were warnings but I did execute my above sample of using something like `wood = wood + (select sum(etc))` which did fail. But anyway, I got your answer, or style, to work. I say style because it caused an error for BUILDING to be capitalized. The warnings I get in phpmyadmin, even if the code works anyway, is 6 total starting with `an expression was expected near (`, `unexpected token near (`, and 4 others I can't just copy/paste.

Comment: But even though they are warnings, I do now have a code that does work and I tested it on my database. And in php to double check.

Comment: I used capital letters, but you can change as you prefer.